# Python / Faker - date, ssn creation from the begining of century

Tags: python, pandas, date, range, faker

I need help directing with use of faker.

Assuming:

```
import pandas as pandas
from faker import Faker
fake=Faker()
ssn=fake.ssn() #generates ssn numbers
```

how to generate ssn number which is:

1. older more than 100 years? -- somehow faker generates not that old
2. ranged in given dates?

please advise

Comment: well, ok, wrote my own generator ;)

Comment: could you make it available brother?